# BASH convert uppercase to lower case and vice versa at same time

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How do i create a program that converts uppercase letters to lower case and vice versa at same time from a given file?
I know how to convert each independently

```
#!/bin/sh
#Program convert upper to lower
cat $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'

#!/bin/sh
#Program convert lower to upper
cat $1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

e.g

hEllo to HeLLO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can readily combine your two lines:

```
$ tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]' <<< "hEllo"
HeLLO
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Bash 4.0 there is a double tilde parameter expansion `${parameter~~pattern}` that toggles the case of all letters in parameter. An example:

```
echo "${1~~}"
```

However, as far as I know, this mechanism is not documented. Hence I do not recommend it for a production use. It is a bad practice to rely on undocumented features.

Answer (score -1):

`tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'` also works!